# A car dealer website with Drupal

Tags: search

Soon I will be starting to develop a car dealer website using Drupal.
I want users to be able to select make, modal and other stuffs.
The main thing is the search; I will be using the Views module, with exposed filters, and taxonomy terms.

Is there any module which can do this?

Comment: I believe you've answered your own question... the Views module with exposed filters can be used for searching site content, just as you've mentioned in your post

Answer (score 2):

There is no specific module to do this but using as you mentioned Views, views exposed filters and taxonomy will give you what you want.

Comment: thankx for ur response, i will start the thing and give a feedback.